# const string reference as non-type template argument

Tags: c++, string, templates, gcc, const-reference

I am trying to have a const string reference as non-type template argument , i am not able to get past this compilation error .

test.h :

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

template<const std::string& V> class TestTmplt
{

};

const std::string& TEST_REF = "TESTREF" ;
typedef  TestTmplt<TEST_REF>  TestRefData ;
```

test.cpp :

```
#include <test.h>

template class TestTmplt<TEST_REF> ;
```

Compilation error :

```
./test.h:10:34: error: could not convert template argument âTEST_REFâ to âconst string& {aka const std::basic_string<char>&}â
./test.h:10:49: error: invalid type in declaration before â;â token
```

I am compiling on centos linux , using following gcc command

```
g++ -c -MMD -MF test.u -g -D_LINUX -std=c++03 -pthread -Wall -DVALGRIND -Wno-missing-field-initializers -z muldefs -I.  -o test.o test.cpp
```

Comment: Strings are created at run time so I don't think you can use them like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `TEST_REF` is not of type `std::string`, but of type `const std::string &`, i.e. it's not an object of type `std::string` and so cannot be used as the template argument. With a slight change, it works:

```
#include <string>

template<const std::string& V> class TestTmplt
{

};

std::string TEST_REF = "TESTREF";

template class TestTmplt<TEST_REF>;
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99881c020bdcd537)

Comment: problem i have is , i have to typedef multiple versions of TEST_REF in the .h and use in other .cpp files, like TEST_REF1, TEST_REF2 and so on. and in test.cpp , i am  defining all the versions .  If i use your solution , and define TEST_REF1, TEST_REF2  i get  multiple definition linking error in my executable.

Comment: @N3Xg3N This has nothing to do with templates, though. Use `extern std::string TEST_REF;` in the header, and define it in one source file.

Comment: Hi Angew, i have a doubt, making it extern , does not make it compile time constant. For template non type argument, the argument must be compile time constant. making it extern, template would know the value only during linking, which defies the fundamentals of template. how is this working ?

Comment: @N3Xg3N Your template parameter is of reference type, which means that the actual argument for it is the *address* of `TEST_REF` (and that *is* a compile-time constant indeed).